# Checkbox with many options

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, checkbox

I created two checkboxes but after clicking on one of them both are marked, as in the picture below, could someone help me solve this problem?

only one can be marked,

[image]

my code:

```
class _LanguageSelectorState extends State<LanguageSelector> {
  static final List<String> languagesList = application.supportedLanguages;
  static final List<String> languageCodesList =
      application.supportedLanguagesCodes;


  final Map<dynamic, dynamic> languagesMap = {
    languagesList[0]: languageCodesList[0],
    languagesList[1]: languageCodesList[1],
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
            title: Text(AppTranslations.of(context).text("settings_language"), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, letterSpacing: 1)),
            elevation: 0.0,
            centerTitle: true,
            bottom: PreferredSize(child: Container(color: Colors.black, height: 0.1), preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0.1),),
          ),
      body: _buildLanguagesList()
    );
  }

  String selectedLanguage = '';

  _buildLanguagesList() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: languagesList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return _buildLanguageItem(languagesList[index]);
      },
    );
  }

   bool _value = false;
  _buildLanguageItem(String language) {
    return CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text(language),
      value: _value,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _value = value;
          application.onLocaleChanged(Locale(languagesMap[language]));
        });
      },
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
    );
  }
}
```

thanks for any help :)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: It seems that checkboxes are in recyclerview, so you should specify that checkbox of which item is marked or unmarked.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example.. Hope that will answer your question how to use checkboxes in listView

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> languagesList = [
  {'value': false},
  {'value': false}
];

  ListView.builder(
      itemCount: languagesList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CheckboxListTile(
          title: Text(languagesList[index]['value'].toString()),
          value: languagesList[index]['value'],
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              languagesList[index]['value'] = value;
            });
          },
          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
        );
      }),
```

The reason your approach didn't work was because you have assigned one variable to all your checkboxes so no wander your checkboxes were updated together

Comment: this won't work because the language list is taken from another source, i edit my main post

Comment: @halohalohalo I don't know what your source looks like.. You have to provide clear question here. Always take your time when asking question to be clear to everyone. Best way is to create a new simple example which is easily reproducible. Help us help you

Answer (score 0):

Because all the widgets created by the `ListView` has the same value `_value`, if one of the widget gets checked, the value for all of the widgets change as the all depend on the same variable.

Here is a demonstration of how you can do it. it may contain errors.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LanguageItem extends StatefulWidget {

  Key key;
  bool isSelected = false;
  YOURCLASS application;
  String language;

  LanguageItem({@required language, @required this.application, this.key 
}):super(key:key);


  @override
  _LanguageItemState createState() => _LanguageItemState();
}

class _LanguageItemState extends State<LanguageItem> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text(widget.language),
      value: widget.isSelected,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          widget.isSelected = value;
          widget.application.onLocaleChanged(Locale(languagesMap[language]));
        });
      },
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @halohalohalo you have to wrap it up in and make a widget, so that each widget will have their own variable

Comment: @halohalohalo check the example

Comment: @halohalohalo you can be creative with this.